# Validator unit test fails because of custom constraint validator

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, junit5

I am writing tests for the constraint validators of my DTOs. They work for every DTO, except for the one which uses a custom written `EmailUniqueConstraintValidator`. This exception occurs:

```
javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call.

    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.SimpleConstraintTree.validateConstraints(SimpleConstraintTree.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.doValidateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:533)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForSingleDefaultGroupElement(ValidatorImpl.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:430)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:169)
    at be.ambrassade.jeugdlink.model.request.UserCreateRequestTest.passwordSizeTooShortOrLongReturnsValidationError(UserCreateRequestTest.java:71)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:532)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:171)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:114)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at be.ambrassade.jeugdlink.validation.EmailUniqueConstraintValidator.isValid(EmailUniqueConstraintValidator.java:33)
    at be.ambrassade.jeugdlink.validation.EmailUniqueConstraintValidator.isValid(EmailUniqueConstraintValidator.java:21)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:171)
    ... 50 more
```

This is the validator:

```
import be.ambrassade.jeugdlink.repo.UserRepository;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class EmailUniqueConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<EmailUnique, String> {

    private UserRepository userRepository;


    public EmailUniqueConstraintValidator(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return value == null || !userRepository.existsByEmail(value);
    }
}
```

It doesn't have a public no arg constructor, but adding one won't solve the issue either due to the repository dependency.

Because of the issue of that custom validator, none of the validation tests for that DTO work. How can I approach this issue?

Comment: How is `UserRepository` injected in `EmailUniqueConstraintValidator` ? I mean in main code, not in test.

Comment: @Benoit via the constructor

Comment: Yes of course... why don't you do the same for your tests ?

Comment: @Benoit because when you setup Spring tests correctly, injection happens automatically.

Comment: @Benoit Because I don't know how to do it with `ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(); validator = factory.getValidator();` If I Mock the repository dependency, I get NullPointer errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read your stacktrace again you will notice that the exception cause was a `NullPointerException`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at be.ambrassade.jeugdlink.validation.EmailUniqueConstraintValidator.isValid(EmailUniqueConstraintValidator.java:33)
```

So the solution to the problem is pretty straightforward, make sure that the `userRepository` field value is not null when you are accessing it in `isValid` method.

Comment: The NullPointer happens when I @Mock the repository dependency, together with `Mockito.when(userRepository.existsByEmail(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(true);`, but it doesn't solve the issue

Comment: You're telling me that you get a `NullPointerException` on the same line even after you are completely sure that `userRepository` on line `33` is not `null`?

Comment: I'm not completely sure about that, otherwise it wouldn't happen. I mocked the repository, so I thought that should solve the dependency issue. But I'm not sure how to solve this

Comment: You can quickly check it out in different ways but running in debug mode with breakpoints is the easiest and simplest way. But the cause of your exception is clearly a `NullPointerException` which happens when you try to access an object that is `null`, and it happens on line `33` where you are accessing `userRepository`. The most logical thing would be to check if that object is null at the point where the exception is thrown before speculating about other complexities. Also read more about `NullPointerException`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html

Comment: I debugged it and it says indeed that `userRepository` is null. @Mock doesn't solve the dependency, maybe that's because I can't `@InjectMocks` it into the validator, because it's not added to the unit test explicitly. After so much trying, I can just solve it by ignoring the specific exception that is caused by that custom constraint validator

Comment: Provided this conversation in addition to the answer helped you solve this issue of understanding what caused you program to throw an exception, would you be so kind to accept my answer? I am asking since your issue was resolved and any further questions should be posted as separate issues. Also an upvote would mark the answer as helpful and constructive. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How is this accepted answer? "You've received NullPointerException because the value is null". Cheers Geoff.

Answer (score 1):

The test suite code is not in the question but according with the problem description this should be the same issue I've been facing recently.

It might be a bit late but I'll post how I solved the problem as it could help other people.

The problem is basically that Hibernate's standard `Validator` implementation that you get by calling `Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator()` does not know anything about Spring's application context so it cannot inject dependencies in your custom constraint validators.

In a Spring application the implementation of both the `Validator` and the `ValidatorFactory` interface is the class `LocalValidatorFactoryBean`, which can delegate to the `ApplicationContext` to instantiate constraint validators with dependencies injected.

What you need to do is

1. Instantiate your constraint validators with their (mocked, I presume) dependencies
2. Create your own `ValidatorFactory` that holds all the constraint validators from bulletpoint 1
3. Instantiate your `Validator` from such factory

This is the custom validator factory

```
public class CustomLocalValidatorFactoryBean extends LocalValidatorFactoryBean {

    private final List<ConstraintValidator<?, ?>> customConstraintValidators;

    public CustomLocalValidatorFactoryBean(List<ConstraintValidator<?, ?>> customConstraintValidators) {
        this.customConstraintValidators = customConstraintValidators;
        setProviderClass(HibernateValidator.class);
        afterPropertiesSet();
    }

    @Override
    protected void postProcessConfiguration(Configuration<?> configuration) {
        super.postProcessConfiguration(configuration);
        ConstraintValidatorFactory defaultConstraintValidatorFactory =
                configuration.getDefaultConstraintValidatorFactory();
        configuration.constraintValidatorFactory(
                new ConstraintValidatorFactory() {
                    @Override
                    public <T extends ConstraintValidator<?, ?>> T getInstance(Class<T> key) {
                        for (ConstraintValidator<?, ?> constraintValidator : customConstraintValidators) {
                            if (key.equals(constraintValidator.getClass())) //noinspection unchecked
                                return (T) constraintValidator;
                        }
                        return defaultConstraintValidatorFactory.getInstance(key);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void releaseInstance(ConstraintValidator<?, ?> instance) {
                        defaultConstraintValidatorFactory
                                .releaseInstance(instance);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

}
```

then in your test class you'd just do something like this:

```
class MyTestSuite {
    
    private final UserRepository mockUserRepository = Mockito.mock(UserRepository.class);
    private final List<ConstraintValidator<?,?>> customConstraintValidators = 
            Collections.singletonList(new EmailUniqueConstraintValidator(mockUserRepository));
    private final ValidatorFactory customValidatorFactory = 
            new CustomLocalValidatorFactoryBean(customConstraintValidators);
    private final Validator validator = customValidatorFactory.getValidator();

    @Test
    void myTestCase() {
        // mock the dependency: Mockito.when(mockUserRepository...)
        User u = new User();
        //setters omitted
        Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> violations = validator.validate(u);
        //assertions on the set of constraint violations
    }

}
```

Hope that helps. You can check out this post of mine for more details: https://codemadeclear.com/index.php/2021/01/26/how-to-mock-dependencies-when-unit-testing-custom-validators/